# issues after CRM 2011 Roll up 14 upgrade

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

After roll 14 upgrade in MS CRM 2011 , we are facing issues in page loading and custom lookups and suggestions for same.

Thanks and regards

Comment: old crm 4 scripts no longer work since UR 12, they need fixing. That said, this is unanswerable without detail about these "issues"

Comment: and why are you not upgrading to UR18? are there any reasons?

Answer (score 0):

UR12 made CRM cross-browser compatible, meaning IE-only code won't work. For us, if I recall correctly, the big issue was selectSingleNode, an IE-only call that we had to make a cross-browser version in our standard library & had to migrate all existing code to call into that library (search and replace). This was a big help when IE 11 got rid of that call entirely.

But without more details of your "issues" we can't really help you.